# Destroying Cookies from SWT's Browser

Tags: java, swt

I've been having trouble with the SWT `Browser` class's management of cookies. The cookies created by the browser appear to persist between sessions, but are difficult to track down and delete.

In particular, I'd like to remove a specific cookie that is created during an authentication process for Stack Exchange.

Right now, I'm able to print out the existing cookie data, but can't figure out how to edit or (ideally) remove the cookie using the `Browser.setCookie` method.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
// Check the 'acct' cookie
System.out.println("Check Cookie: " + Browser.getCookie("acct", "http://www.stackexchange.com"));
//  Outputs "Check Cookie: t=X123X&s=X123X" [redacted id's] 

// Try to reset the cookie
Browser.setCookie("acct=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT", "http://www.stackexchange.com");

// Read the cookie back again
System.out.println("Updated Cookie: " + Browser.getCookie("acct", "http://www.stackexchange.com"));
//  Outputs "Updated Cookie: t=X123X&s=X123X" [same data as before]
```

Because there is no clear methods to view cookies stored by the SWT browser, or to clear all cookies stored, I'm a bit stuck as to how to reset these values. I've tried a few variations of the `setCookie()` arguments with no success so far.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDoc of `Browser#setCookie()`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html) is quite clear:

> Sets a cookie on a URL. Note that cookies are shared amongst all Browser instances. The value parameter must be a cookie header string that complies with RFC 2109. The value is passed through to the native browser unchanged.
>
> Example value strings: foo=bar (**basic session cookie**) foo=bar; path=/; domain=.eclipse.org (**session cookie**) foo=bar; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-2030 00:00:01 GMT (**persistent cookie**) foo=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT (**deletes cookie** foo)

The code below creates a cookie, then prints it, deletes it and prints again.

Output:

> Cookie foo: bar
>
> Cookie foo: null

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/";

    /* Set the cookie */
    Browser.setCookie("foo=bar", url);

    System.out.println("Cookie foo: " + Browser.getCookie("foo", url));

    /* Delete the cookie by setting to expired date */
    Browser.setCookie("foo=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT", url);

    System.out.println("Cookie foo: " + Browser.getCookie("foo", url));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't appear to fix my issue, I've updated my question to use the cookie reset method you described, however the before/after output for the cookie remains the same.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can just copy/paste/run your code to see what's wrong?

Comment: Alright, I've made a demo MCVE which replicates the issue I have. As full disclosure, the link the browser loads is for a Stack Exchange plugin OAuth flow, and logging into it will send me an access token that allows my plugin to post/interact with stack overflow under the user logged in. Although Im a good guy, if you wish to log in safely, it's best to use a Stack Exchange account that isn't your main profile. https://gist.github.com/apclapp/8a9a85a4244b16159a242f185d473682

Comment: To reiterate a point there, logging in to the URL loaded by the browser is still a voluntary process- opening the program alone will not grant an access token.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 I believe you when you say you won't use the information for evil purposes, but I'd rather not use any of my accounts. Can you reproduce your problem without the need to use an actual account, i.e. can you create a scenario that just sets a cookie but still shows the problems you've been experiencing?

Comment: I created a PHP page that sets a cookie in a similar format to the ones from Stack Exchange, and adjusted to gist to use this site instead of involving any Stack Exchange auth process [ https://gist.github.com/apclapp/06293fff0394906d2abc7674adc6452e ]. However, when I changed the URL's in the application to use this site instead, the code cleared the 'acct' cookie perfectly fine.

Comment: Is there something unclear about how the Browser does cookie lookups? I imagine the cookie is actually created by an 'https://'-prefixed page, and in my (chrome) browser, the cookie displays as being for '.stackexchange.com'. I wonder if the SWT browser truncates the "http://" part of the URL when it does a lookup, but it includes it when trying to use "setcookie()"? It's a bit of a shot in the dark, but I'm thoroughly confused at the moment- the source for these SWT.Browser functions are a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Apologies for the triple-reply, but to formalize my previous point: Will the same URL argument used to retrieve a cookie with 'Browser.getCookie' *always* work for 'Browser.setCookie'.

Comment: To answer my own question in the previous comment, getCookie() *does* allow different (including invalid) URL lookup strings for cookies, and presumably setCookie() requires a more specific URL, which I still can't figure out. A short note of results with an invalid lookup argument is provided here: https://gist.github.com/apclapp/9636967256042fb408d0cd36d1063a52

Comment: @Hiphop03199 I'm afraid I can't be of more help here. You could try clearing the cookie from javascript (dev console in your browser)  and see if that works. If so, run the js from SWT. I doubt it'll work though.

Comment: I gave it a go with "browser.evaluate("document.cookie = 'acct=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;'");" But security policies prevent doing this sort of cookie manipulation, as expected. Thanks again for the help going through this, I think I'll be scratching my head a bit longer on this one.